# Sending push notification without server: web app to android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm totally new to hybrid world so I have to ask first.

**Can I send notifications through GCM without a server?**

I mean, I'm building a SPA with AngularJS and Firebase, but my customer asked me to make a dashboard for Android, so every time an user makes an order, they (both dashboard administrators) receive a PUSH notification on their phone: "A new order has been created", and when they "tap", the application opens.

I've been reading something about `/topic/` endpoint to notify both of them, but I think I still need a server to do it. Do I?
It would be great if I simply `post` a http query using something like AngularJS' `$http` service to tell GCM to send a notification for that `topic`/`usergroup`.

Is that possible? If so, any idea about how?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you have not read, try the following links http://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/ and http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr and [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25)

Comment: @BNK where are the notifications? I can't see anything about push notifications on that site.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr. You will find its usage definition (`...is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a downstream GCM message can be done "without a server". One option is to send an HTTP request to GCM containing the required fields. [Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) is available with GCM which does make it easier to send downstream messages without a server. Your client apps can subscribe for messages from /topic/usergroup and then you can send an HTTP request with /topic/usergroup as your "to" value, and subscribed clients will get it.

Note that you will need to set up a Google Developer Console project to get the required API key.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) for more information on the structure of GCM HTTP downstream messages.

Comment: Both links are broken